# Identify conserved sequences in lists of integers

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have lists of integers :

```
   [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,10,11,12],
    [3,4,-5,6,7,8,11,12,2,2],
    [etc]]
```

- a number can be found 0, 1 or multiple times in each list
- the sign can be negative

I need to find the motifs that are conserved in all the lists. Here, the result would be only one motif (which I found manually) :

```
 [[3,4,5,6,7],
 [-7,-6,-5,-4,-3],
 [3,4,-5,6,7]]
```

By "motif", I mean a sequence of numbers (at least 2 digits) that is found in all the lists : here for an example, the numbers 3,4,5,6,7 are found in this consecutive order in all the lists, though the order is reversed in the second list.
Ideally, the detection of the motifs would allows a small number of differences

Any ideas ?

I thought that using networkX could help me identify "cliques" but I do not find a function that would help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please define what you mean by motif's that are conserved. Also would be good if you explained how you got the output from the input? And what you have done till now

Comment: The question kind of looks like a homework assignment rather than an actual application.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer There is nothing wrong with getting homework help on SO, there is even a [tag:homework] tag. However, OP you should still be posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with your question.

Comment: is this a [Longest Common Substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)?

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer thank you for your kind comment. This is not a homework assignment but a problem I have been trying to solve for almost a week now

Comment: Its a Longest common Substring problem and you can use Suffix trees to solve it.

Comment: Thank you @mukesh. This problem seems indeed related to Longest Common Substring problem. Would it not rather be a Longest Common Subsequence problem ? I'll try to looking for suffix trees.

Comment: @mescalinum thanks I'll look for documentation on that. My first idea was to use alignments but I've never tried to align more than one sequences, plus with an arbitrary "alphabet", only two with ACGT or codons ;)

Comment: If the numbers don't have to be consecutive then it would be Longest Common Subsequence problem.

Comment: 2 is also common in all the sublists

Comment: @mukesh ok thanks ! I will try with consecutive numbers for a start. Later, I'll try inserting gaps and small inversions then.

Comment: @WhyOhWhy In expected output there should be a 2 in every sublist

Comment: @Ajay True, but it is not really part of a sequence : list 1 and list 2 have (1,2) but not list 3. I'll precise that I need sequences longer than 1 element in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first find one intersect between all of sub lists based on the absolute values of the sub lists then loop over all sub lists and find the desire intersection :

```
def find_intersection(m_list):
        temp=[map(abs,i) for i in m_list]
        v=set(temp[0])
        for k in temp[1:]:
            v=v.intersection(k)

        for i,k in enumerate(m_list):
            m_list[i]={t for t in k if abs(t) in v}

        return m_list


l=[[1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, 10, 11, 12], [3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 2, 2]]

print find_intersection(l)
```

result :

```
[set([2, 4, 6, 7, -5, -3]), set([2, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3]), set([2, 3, 4, 6, 7, -5])]
```

Comment: I've got a similar solution but In his expected output there is no 2 in each sublist

Comment: he says it's not part of sequence...it appeared in a latter sequence but  in the same list

Comment: @Ajay maybe 2 doesn't presents in another lists!!

Comment: @Kasra thank you. Intersecting the lists was also my first idea, but I then I am stuck when I try to identify sublists which have their digits in the same relative order

Comment: @Ajay in fact the order of the digits matter. 2 would be part of the motif if we had for example [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,8,9],
    [1,2,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,10,11,12],
    [3,4,-5,6,7,2,8,11,12,2,2],
    [etc]]

Answer (score 0):

a is your list

```
In [78]: b=[[abs(i) for i in elem] for elem in a]

In [81]: c=list(set.intersection(*map(set, b)))


In [84]: [list({i for i in elem if abs(i) in c}) for elem in a]
Out[84]: [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3], [3, 4, -5, 6, 7,  2]]
```